How can I style javascript without using img class? And how can I use onclick button but also have a functional nav bar?
I am creating a collage where you click around, and the pictures pop up where clicked. It looks how I want but now the nav bar doesn't work as I can't click it. Also, since I am using img in css for this it affects the rest of my website.


const images = [
  "collage1.webp", "collage2.jpg", "collage3.jpg", "collage4.jpg", "collage5.jpg", "collage6.jpg"
]

let i = 0


function placeImage(x, y) {

  const nextImage = images[i]


  const img = document.createElement("img")
  img.setAttribute("src", nextImage)
  img.style.left = x + "px"
  img.style.top = y + "px"
  img.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5) rotate(" + (Math.random() * 20 - 10) + "deg)"
  document.body.appendChild(img)


  i = i + 1

  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})

document.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("background3.jpg");
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*background-color: #214a63;*/
  /*#0A1128*/
  /*display:flex;*/
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4db1f0;
  color: white;
}


/*test for favicon menu item*/

.topnav a.split {
  float: right;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/*
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}*/

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}


/*for floating selfie*/

.flier.self {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}


/*for linked in logo*/

.linkedin {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}


/* for the about me page (looks good but gets rid of linked in image and cant click tabs)*/

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 400px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  animation: fadein 0.5;
}
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="vacation.html">Vacation Spots</a>
    <a href="eightBall.html">Magic Eight Ball</a>
    <a href="dog.html">My Dog</a>
    <a href="linked in goes here" target="_blank" class="split"> <img src="LI-In-Bug.png" class="linkedin"></a>
  </div>

  <h1>About Me</h1>

  <script src="collage.js"></script>

</body>




Remove the event.preventDefault() from your click handler.

You should restrict the click function to a specific . I cannot see a good reason why you would want someone to draw a collage over the top of the main menu, so why not place all of the collage images inside a ?



const images = [
  "collage1.webp", "collage2.jpg", "collage3.jpg", "collage4.jpg", "collage5.jpg", "collage6.jpg"
]

let i = 0


function placeImage(x, y) {

  const nextImage = images[i]


  const img = document.createElement("img")
  img.setAttribute("src", nextImage)
  img.style.left = x + "px"
  img.style.top = y + "px"
  img.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5) rotate(" + (Math.random() * 20 - 10) + "deg)"
  img.classList.add("collage")
  document.body.appendChild(img)


  i = i + 1

  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})

document.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
  
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("background3.jpg");
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*background-color: #214a63;*/
  /*#0A1128*/
  /*display:flex;*/
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4db1f0;
  color: white;
}


/*test for favicon menu item*/

.topnav a.split {
  float: right;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/*
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}*/

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}


/*for floating selfie*/

.flier.self {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}


/*for linked in logo*/

.linkedin {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}


/* for the about me page (looks good but gets rid of linked in image and cant click tabs)*/

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
}

.collage {
  position: absolute;
 
}
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="vacation.html">Vacation Spots</a>
    <a href="eightBall.html">Magic Eight Ball</a>
    <a href="dog.html">My Dog</a>
    <a href="linked in goes here" target="_blank" class="split"> <img src="LI-In-Bug.png" class="linkedin"></a>
  </div>

  <h1>About Me</h1>

  <script src="collage.js"></script>

</body>



